# Getting previous days file from a folder using Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have excel files (.xlsx) in a specific folder location with a format for e.g. : FileName_yyyymmdd.xlsx. The files are archived in this location. I would like to pick the previous days file and read it.

I need to do this in Excel VBA programming.

I understand that I need to first sort the folder based on "Date Last modified". How do I do this and what next after that?

Please help with a sample code.

Comment: Happy to help out with your code and where you are stuck. But please don't ask for code point blank. Conceptually, you don't need to sort anything at all. You can easily get today's date in VBA, then subtract one day and create the file name from that date, no?. Then open that file. Again, if you are stuck, post your code so far and point out what you need help with.

Comment: Well, `Date` will give you todays date, you may need to take into account weekends - on a Monday is the previous day going to be Friday - so you'll need `WeekDay` to figure out the day of the week, maybe a list of bank  holidays as the previous day on a Tuesday after a BH is Friday, you'll also need `Format` to put the date in the correct order for your file name.  Or maybe `FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` if you want to manually select the file.